# Adaptive UI for iOS project having xib files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a project which is having .xib files and i want to make it adaptive to all the ios devices but the videos which are shown in the apple developer site are for storyboards, the problem is i am not much experienced with the ios development and if there is any tutorial for giving adaptivity to the app which are having .xib then please give me the link. I am totally clueless with this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no difference in storyboard and xib for auto layout. You can follow the same for both. Refer: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be be storyboard. Autolayout works fine with Xib as well.

Comment: Ok thanks to both of you, ill then follow the video and try to work on it. :-)